# update two table in single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two table in sql the 1st table is for account while the 2nd table is for testimonial . i am trying to update the two tables in single query. The update is successful if the account already have a testimonial but fails to update if the account has no testimonial yet .How can i fix this heres my code for the update ....

```
if(!$update=mysql_query(
                "UPDATE
                     tblapplicant,
                     tbltestimonial
                 SET
                     tblapplicant.ImagePath='".$name."',
                     tbltestimonial.pic = '".$name."'
                 WHERE
                     tblapplicant.appid=tbltestimonial.appid"
            )
    )
```

Comment: **STOP** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO with prepared statements instead.

Comment: yes . but any help with how can i fix the main issue

Comment: can you post the two table structures to further help you.

Comment: I assume, `tbltestimonial` has more columns than just `pic`. How do you expect MySQL to fill these columns for you?

Comment: Switch to ANSI JOIN syntax. Replace the inner join with an outer one

Comment: tbltestimonial fields appid,stdname,pic .....
tblapplicant fields appid,stdname,ImagePath....

Comment: tbltestimonial fields appid,stdname,pic .....
tblapplicant fields appid,stdname,ImagePath.... 

what im trying to do is for example the applicant create a testimonial it will be inserted in tbltestimonial getting the session of applicant as stated here(appid,stdname,ImagePath) . now if the applicant updated his/her photo both tblapplicant and tbltestimonial should be both updated .. in my code above it is successfully updating however fails if the applicant have no testimonial yet wherein i am somehow confused

Comment: So your picture should load into the account table for the applicant. You would perform an Inner Join for your testimonial page to include the applicants picture on the testimonial page. User data stays with the user... Testimonial data stays on the testimonial. If you need both, you join one based on the ID of the testimonial. Your testimonial should be ... appid,accountid AS FK__tblapplicant__tbltestmonial, ... other fields here

Comment: Once you've loaded the picture into their account, I don't think you really need image path really. That should just go away after you get the users folder path.... I believe there's more needed to be updated into this but... I think the original question and approach was off track.

Comment: Added some quick changes - I haven't tested but I'm assuming you have a dev copy that you can test this against, right?

Comment: You cant update 2 tables in the same statement

Comment: stll not working .. is it possible to create two update but still in single submition ?

Comment: IF you put them in a transaction,yes

Comment: @Strawberry as I understood the question, he wants the testimonial to come into existence, when none is there. What else should he try with updating `tbltestimonial.pic`?

Comment: @cdonat Apologies - I think you're right

Answer (score 1):

1) You're working with a database, it defeats the purpose to use the same data being inserted into two different tables.

2) One gentleman also mentioned stop using MySQL... heres some reference code for you. Assuming you're using php.

3) If you want to use a single query to update 2 tables with the same info against recommendation. Use a stored procedure to update them both.

4) At which point are these account's interconnected in this query? I'm somehow intrigued if this system is in beta or testing?

With your "Where" conditions without matching a specific record, this will update every record that has a matching ID. This is highly not recommended until you add further conditions like username = .... or a condition that's specific to someone or a specific set of rows.

**I strongly advise you post the tables you're working with and what results you want achieve for the best advise. **

Can't really give a good consultation with you playing the whole overview close to the chest. Using this plain-Jane without further detail on what you're asking for is at your own risk my friend.

**include/dbconnect.php optional recommended update**

```
<?php
if (isset($mysqli)){
    unset($mysqli);
}
define("HOST", "yo.ur.ip.addr");     // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "myfunctionalaccount");    // The database username. 
define("PASSWORD", "superdoopersecurepassword!");    // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "thegoods");
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
?>
```

functions.php  <-- shouldn't be called functions if its going to be your form response

```
<?php
// SHOULD BE SOME MASSIVE LOGIC UP HERE FOR FORM DATA DECISIONING
include_once "include/dbconnect.php";
$name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))); 
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("CALL UpdateTestimonials(?,?,?)"){
        $stmt->bind_param($name, $image, $userid);
        $stmt->execute();
        // optional to show affected rows
        $stmt->affected_rows
        //
        // use if you want to return values from DB
        // $stmt->bind_result($result);
        // $stmt->fetch;            
}
$stmt->close
?>
```

MySQL build a stored procedure - fyi; definer is optional. Definer will allow you to run a query that only elevated privileges can access due to the safety of such a query. You can use create procedure w/o the definer parameter. dT is just an abbreviation for datatype. You would put varchar or int... etc..

```
use 'database';
DROP procedure if exists 'UpdateTestimonials';
DELIMITER $$
use 'UpdateTestimonials' $$
CREATE DEFINER='user'@'HOSTNAME/LOCALHOST/%' PROCEDURE 'mynewprocedure' (IN varINPUT varchar, IN varIMG blob, IN varAppID int)
BEGIN
    UPDATE tblapplicant 
    SET imagepath = varINPUT,
        pic       = LOAD_FILE(varIMG)
    WHERE appid = varAppID
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT JOIN:

```
if (!$update = mysql_query(
            "UPDATE
                 tblapplicant 
                 LEFT JOIN tbltestimonial ON tblapplicant.appid = tbltestimonial.appid
             SET
                 tblapplicant.ImagePath = '" . $name . "',
                 tbltestimonial.pic = '" . $name . "'"
        )
)
```

Also, if you need some additional filters for tbltestimonial, add them into LEFT JOIN condition

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a transaction. BTW also please use prepared statements to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

```
<?php
  // prefer mysqli over mysql. It is the more modern library.
  $db = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");

  $db->autocommit(false); // begin a new transaction

  // prepare statements
  $update_applicant = 
    $db->prepare("UPDATE tblapplicant
                  SET    tblapplicant.ImagePath = ?"));
  $update_applicant->bind_param("s", $name));
  $update_applicant->execute();

  $update_testimonial = 
    $db->prepare("UPDATE tbltestimonial
                  SET    tbltestimonial.pic = ?"));
  $update_testimonial->bind_param("s", $name))
  $update_testimonial->execute();

  $db->commit(); // finish the whole transaction as successful,
                 // when everything has succeeded.
?>
```

Of course that would not create any testimonials, that don't exist. It just updates those, that do. When you want to insert new entries in `tbltestimonial`, do so explicitly with an `INSERT` statement inside the transaction.

MySQL does not fully support transactions. The tables have to use a table type, that can handle them, e.g. `innodb`. When that is the case, the transaction will make sure, that everyone else either sees all changes from the transactions, or none.

In many cases transactions allow you to perform a group of simple steps, that otherwise would need complex single queries or would not be possible without transactions at all.

**Alternative Solution**

Another approach of course would be an update-trigger. Create a trigger in your database, that fires whenever e.g. `tblapplicant` is updated and updates `tbltestimonial` accordingly. Then you don't have to care about that in your application code.